# Navigation setup for site pages

Tags: navigation, default-document

I have a navigation defined in Site actions -> Look and Feel -> Navigations.
I have a home page (Root page) - Home.aspx. Let's say I have created two more pages like A.aspx and B.aspx.

Now I would like to have my navigation on the home page, however I do not want my navigations to appear in the custom pages A & B. How can I do it?

Comment: Creating a Page Layout in SharePoint 2010[link](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=71)
[link](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2010/02/17/changing-page-layout-with-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)

Comment: I would for a special page layout that takes care of the differences as Ziga says.

Comment: Thank you Niranjan, for your link !! Will make use of it. Hi Chris thanks for your thoughts, will do it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new pagelayout or edit an existing one and in them add some css or javascript in the AdditionalHeadPlaceHolder which should hide the navigation. This is a better approach than adding css or javascript in the masterpage validating parameters to then decide wether or not elements should be hidden.

http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2010/02/17/changing-page-layout-with-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your help, How can I create a new page layout?

Comment: @Jithu Look at the link I added to my answer

Comment: That was just great, Thank you for sharing it, now one more related question - How can I select this created layout for only one page. All other pages should use the default layouts.

Comment: @Jithu That really depends on how you create your pages. In order to create a page with a specific pagelayout (Through standard SP UI) you'll have to navigate to the Pages list on the site and in there select **Add new page** and here you select what pagelayout the new page should use. Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the css and javascript to hide the navigation from particular page.You may have to include the same in the page a&b

Thanks 
Dhanya